# JPA: Unidirectional ManyToMany with existing object to be inserted

Tags: jpa

```
User {

Set<Book> _books;

@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
              name="BLETAG_LABEL",
              joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TAG_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
              inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="LABEL_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
Set<Book>getBooks();

}

Book {

}
```

. If I set the CascadeType to PERSIST and I try to create a User with an existing book (book1) like this, an unique constraint is fired...

Book book1 = new Book("book1");
user.getBooks().add(book1);

. My current solution is to the the CascadeType to MERGE and check for all user.getBooks() if the book already exist. If the book does not exist, I need to create it (because not CascadeType.PERSIST)

Is it the right solution ?
Is there any better "automatic" solution available for this kind of use case ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the Book from the current persistence context, cascade persist should work fine, and only persist the new Books.  If your Book is detached, then you first need to merge or find it in the current persistence context.